# 2-way set associative cache hit/miss checking

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I have 256 blocks with 16 byte per block. I'm trying to define miss or hit the hexadecimal addresses according to 2-way set associative cache. I doubt that the second can be miss because of  2-way set associative? I think as hit but I'm not sure.

```
2ABC10A2

2ABC10A7

4BBC10A0

2ABC10A9
```

So If I have 16 bytes per block, I have `2^4` then 4 bits that means respectively my offsets are `2, 7, 0, 9`. If I have 256 blocks, I have `2^8` then 8 bits index that means `0A` the remains are tags. I think I'm right up to here. So I get the table but I'm not for miss/hit part. Are they right? If there are mistake, could you fix? I want to learn. Thanks.

```
TAG          INDEX              BLOCK DATA                                HIT/MISS

2ABC1         0A         2ABC10A0 + 16 BYTE  (2ABC10A0  - 2ABC10AF )        MISS
2ABC1         0A               2ABC10A0 + 16 BYTE                           HIT
4BBC1         0A                4BBC10A0 + 16 BYTE                          MISS
2ABC1         0A                2ABC10A0 + 16 BYTE                          HIT
```

Answer (score 0):

The miss/hit part is correct.

The index bit width is 7 not 8. For 256 blocks 2-way set associative cache, index bit width is  log<sub>2</sub>(256/2) = 7.

To be more accurate the miss/hit part is correct assuming that all the accesses are loads (read operations). If stores (write operations) are included then it depends on the choice of cache write policies.